# How to hide menu item of AttachedFlyout menu?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am able to display a right clicked menu using the below code programmatically, showing/hiding required menu-items is easy, since we can create MenuFlyoutItem as we wish.

```
private void MyGrid_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MenuFlyout myFlyout = new MenuFlyout();
    MenuFlyoutItem mnu1 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Rename" };    
    MenuFlyoutItem mnu2 = new MenuFlyoutItem { Text = "Delete" };    
    myFlyout.Items.Add(mnu1);   
    myFlyout.Items.Add(mnu2);
    mnu1.Click += mnu1_Click;
    mnu2.Click += mnu2_Click;

    FrameworkElement senderElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
    myFlyout.ShowAt(sender as UIElement, e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement));
}
```

But, When I create menu using xaml as AttachedFlyout, I am unable to hide a particular menu item. here is my code:

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
..............
        <Grid Name="GrdForFolderMenu">
            <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout >
                <MenuFlyout Placement="Right">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Name="MenuFolderCreate" Text="New Folder" Click="MenuFolderCreate_Click" DataContext="Folders"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Name="MenuFolderRename"  Text="Rename" Click="MenuFolderRename_Click"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Name="MenuFolderExport"  Text="Export" Click="MenuFolderExport_Click" />
                    <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Name="MenuFolderDelete"  Text="Delete" Click="MenuFolderDelete_Click" />
                </MenuFlyout>
            </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        ......
        ........
```

Here is my right click event:

```
private void myListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{            
  FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
}
```

Struggling for a long to hide particular menu item, in code! Please help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to get the `MenuFlyout` and either set the `Visibility` of the specific `MenuFlyoutItem` to `Collapsed` or remove it from the list.

```
if (FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender) is MenuFlyout menuFlyout)
{
    // Hide 'MenuFolderExport' MenuFlyoutItem
    //menuFlyout.Items[2].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    // Or, remove 'MenuFolderExport' MenuFlyoutItem
    menuFlyout.Items.Remove(menuFlyout.Items[2]);
}

FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout((FrameworkElement)sender);
```

I'd also attach the `RightTapped` to your `GrdForFolderMenu` and replace all `Name="xxx"` with `x:Name="xxx"`.